# For-Each Loop in TextArea

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

When I tried to use a Handlebars ForEach-loop within a plain HTML textarea, I encountered some to me unexpected behaviour.

First let me show you my code:

**My template.html:**

```
<template name="test">
  <textarea>
    {{#each array}}
      {{this}}
    {{/each}}
  </textarea>
</template>
```

**My template.js:**

```
Template.test.array = function(){
    return ["String1", "String2", "String3"];
}
```

**The Problem:**

I actually expected some output that looks like that:

```
String1 
String2 
String3
```

Instead I got this:

```
<!--data:46XrgsL9aX8aCa3Ek-->
<!--data:tu6FiCxRraSLoh2w9-->
<!--data:5h3PkyB66dHw4zrWF-->
```

As a workaround I used a Handlebars helper and manipulated the value of the textarea utilizing jQuery, which worked perfectly.

Still I would like to get some clarification about this case:

1. **Why don't I get the expected output? If I use the loop outside of the textarea, it prints the Strings properly.**
2. **What are these Strings? JavaScript's internal object-IDs or the like?**

Every little help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

These strings look like [Spark landmarks](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Spark). This is weird, but may be fixed in the rewrite of the rendering engine in the next Meteor release.

This may be related to an issue when a string literal as passed as the context to a helper; it gets turned into an object.

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1447

One way to go back to a string literal is to write a helper. Instead of `{{this}}`, write `{{printString}}`, and define

```
Template.test.printString = function() { return "" + this; }
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, first of thank you very much for your answer. I actually tried to utilize a helper method already (and tried it again just some seconds ago) and it still produces this weird output. +1 for the hint about the Spark landmarks!

Comment: Can you try un-escaping the output, as in `{{{this}}}` or `{{{printString}}}` (three curly braces)?

Comment: Still thank you very much for your contribution. Maybe someone else has a brilliant idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this should work! If it still doesn't after Andrew's suggestions, try these:

1) Move the data outside of the helper:

```
var array = ["String1", "String2", "String3"];
Template.test.array = function(){
  return array;
};
```

2) Wrap the data entries in objects, as a workaround:

```
Template.test.array = function(){
  return [{label: "String1"}, {label: "String2"}, {label: "String3"}];
};

{{#each array}}
  {{label}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hey Hubert, tried both suggestions. Both did again lead to the bad output. I made sure that every thing should actually work by also filling a list in the same way. The list looks fine, the textarea does not.